# Using difflib.get_close_matches to replace word in string - Python

Tags: python, difflib

If `difflib.get_close_matches` can return a single close match. Where I supply the sample string and close match. How can I utilize the 'close match' to replace the string token found?

```
# difflibQuestion.py

import difflib

word = ['Summerdalerise', 'Winterstreamrise']
line = 'I went up to Winterstreamrose.'

result = difflib.get_close_matches(line,word,n=1)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Winterstreamrise']
```

I want to produce the line:

```
I went up to Winterstreamrise.
```

For **many lines and words.**

I have checked the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

- can't find any ref to string index of found match difflib.getget_close_matches
- the other module classes & functions return lists

I Googled "python replace word in line using difflib" etc. I can't find any reference to anyone else asking/writing about it. It would seem a common scenario to me.

This example is of course a simplified version of my 'real world' scenario. Which may be of help. Since I am dealing more with table data (rather than line)

```
Surname, First names, Street Address, Town, Job Description
```

And my 'words' are a large list of street base names eg MAIN, EVERY, EASY, LOVERS (without the Road, Street, Lane) So my difflib.get_close_matches could be used to substitute the string of column x 'line' with the closest match 'word'.

However I would appreciate anyone suggesting an approach to either of these examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
import difflib

possibilities = ['Summerdalerise', 'Winterstreamrise']
line = 'I went up to Winterstreamrose.'

newWords = []
for word in line.split():
    result = difflib.get_close_matches(word, possibilities, n=1)
    newWords.append(result[0] if result else word)
result = ' '.join(newWords)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
I went up to Winterstreamrise
```

Explanation:

- The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) show a first argument named `word`, and there is no suggestion that `get_close_matches()` has any awareness of sub-words within this argument; rather, it reports on the closeness of a match between this word atomically and the list of `possibilities` supplied as the second argument.
- We can add the awareness of words within `line` by splitting it into a list of such words which we iterate over, calling `get_close_matches()` for each word separately and modifying the word in our result only if there is a match.

Comment: Thank you for your input including your answer. Excellent. I appreciate your thoroughness.  I was curious about your use of the term 'atomically'. I assume you mean a unitary action or object that is essentially indivisible, unchangeable, whole, and irreducible. However the `get_close_matches()` docs do say: 'word is a sequence for which close matches are desired (typically a string)'. I would consider a string divisible? That is a string can be divided into tokens (words delimited by space chars) as well as the actual characters that make up the string.

Comment: All I meant was that `get_close_matches()` makes its assessment based on the full string argument `word`, and any internal use of substrings is opaque to the caller, so this function's operation is effectively 'atomic' (i.e., no information is made available to the caller regarding whether any particular substring of the `word` argument was the determining factor in the function's return value).